# LibreOffice SUMIF specific time

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'd like to sum order totals and have 2 subtotals for orders taken *before and after 17:00*.

The formula: `=SUMIF(C:C,">17:00",D:D)`
where C and D columns are:
[image: Picture link]

The formula does not work well. I guess it considers "17:00" as a whole date.

Is there a way to sum all the orders that where taken after 5pm?

Comment: Maybe your Heure column does not contain the datatype Time. Maybe that is a Text datatype.

Comment: It is a Datetime field. In the meantime I found a dirty trick : adding a column =HOUR(C8) and comparing to this one in the sumif

Answer (score 0):

Change the cells' format and set it to Time.

[image]

Then your formula should work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't change the cell type, change your criteria to ">17/24" or ">0.70833333333" instead of ">17:00".  Hours are calculated in fractions of a whole 24 hour day.  If you're looking for values greater than 17, you'll never get there. It gets to 1 and then starts over at 0.

As an experiment, try typing 17:00 or 5:00 PM into a cell in Excel.  Excel will generally recognize that as a date/time.  Then change the type to General, and you'll see 0.70833333333.

Excel does math with dates by counting the number of days from January 0, 1900.  A value of 1 is midnight on January 1, 1900.  A value of 1.5 is noon on January 1, 1900.  A value of 1.70833333333 is 5:00 PM on January 1, 1900.

Right now, it is June 15, 2021 at 12:33PM which is 44,362.5234137... days since the turn of the 20th century.

[image]

Experiment with it by typing any number and changing the cell type to a date and/or time.